# Why would my update function be taking 85% of time if I left it blank?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, instruments, swift4, skscene

I'm a bit confused while time profiling my app. I've noticed that as it goes on the CPU usage increases, but I am not sure why. Even when the player is idle there seems to be a 72% CPU usage seemingly coming from `[SKScene _update:]` My update function is blank because my game is turn based, so why would there be so much going on here?

Any tips would be appreciated.

[image]

In case it needs to be said, this is my update method:

```
override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    // Called before each frame is rendered
}
```

Additional Info:

The main game map is a hex-based `SKTileMapNode` with a UI drawn using `SKCameraNode`. The UI is made up of about 30 nodes include `SKLabelNode` and `SKSpriteNode` There is an AI that is run on a separate thread every time the user ends their turn. When the AI runs, the Main thread CPU usage instantly drops as seen in the image above. This is strange because the AI only runs the `GKMinMaxStrategist` `bestMoveForPlayer()` function.

Answer (score 1):

You may be manually calling `update(_:)` which in turns calls `update(_:)` again, you should be **overriding** this method to update the scene even if you have an empty implementation. Ensure you have set the `SKSceneDelegate` of your scene.

> Do not call this method directly; it is called exactly once per frame,
>   so long as the scene is presented in a view and is not paused. By
>   default, this method does nothing. Your scene subclass should override
>   this method and perform any necessary updates to the scene.

you may also pause/resume the view manually:

```
 override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    guard let view = view else {
        return
    }

    view.paused = !view.paused
}
```

Comment: I most definitely have overridden update and left it blank. Also, what does SKSceneDelegate have to do with this exactly?

Comment: all scene processing methods can be delegated with `SKSceneDelegate`, without the relevant code I could not tell wether you are subclassing and implementing your own delegate. try pausing the view when the player's turn has ended and updating it before it begins.

Comment: So I explicitly never do anything with the `SKSceneDelegate` I don't access it or work with any of its functionality. There is nowhere I call `update` manually and pausing the view defeats the purpose since the user cannot make any moves.

Comment: I understand, Are you running any loops in the main thread that would cause the scene/view to update.

Comment: What would be an example of such a loop? I don't believe I have anything running until the player makes a touch input.

Comment: I ask because it appears to me that you are creating a disposable resource that is added to the `contiguous array` for the scene and later released by [ARC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_Reference_Counting) Does this problem occur on a device as well as the simulator? it may just be some quark of the simulators ARC.

Comment: I've only been testing on device so I think the data is accurate. In general running for a lengthy amount of time, the CPU usage increases over time as turns are taken. It seems the `contiguous array` persists as a big chunk of CPU time. Would this be some SKTexture data?

Comment: possibly if you are not using a group, texture mapping could be cpu/gpu intensive, but this would show in your fps.

Comment: My FPS counter stays pretty solid on 60, draws get up to 100 or so. But its Worrisome on CPU usage